# How to pass a property as a method parameter then set it to nil in a block in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I have the following situation where I'm sending in the property `self.view`, which holds some view, as a parameter to the below method:

```
- (void) someMethod:(UIView *)view
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
     {
        //blablabla
     }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        view = nil;
     }];
}
```

Where the compiler is telling me:

> Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)

I do try adding the block type specifier to the parameter and that doesn't work. I'm wanting it so that when I set view to `nil`, it will also set the property `self.view` to `nil`. I am having trouble wrapping my head around this situation especially when you throw the block into it, I think normally I would need a double pointer?

I'm wondering what is the best way to approach this where I can `self.view` to `nil` using the parameter in the method block.

Comment: How are you imagining this will work? What is it you think is going to get set to `nil` and when? `view` is just a reference; what would nilifying that reference do, do you think?

Comment: @matt Disregard my previous response to your comment. I've updated the question to make it more clear (sorry this memory stuff confuses me sometimes).

Comment: Right, but setting `view` the parameter to `nil`, even if you were to do that, is not going to have any effect on `self.view`. That is my point.

Comment: @matt Yeah I just realized that. I guess what I'm asking is how would I accomplish setting self.view as nil in the completion block by sending it through as parameter to this method? I'm now messing around with trying to use a double pointer as the parameter but struggling with that.

Comment: I don’t get why you’d want to do that. What’s the larger context here?

Comment: @matt what's happening in that animation block of code is self.view is sliding off the screen as another view replaces it (the user pushes a button to bring the new view onto the screen). So at that point, I want to get rid of self.view from memory until I have to create it again, no use in keeping a copy of it around.

Comment: Well is this method going to be called with different views? I mean, why shouldn't the completion handler set `self.view` to `nil` if it's your method and your view?

Comment: @matt Yeah I need it for some different scenarios. I'm hacking on some new functionality and rather than redesign from the ground up, I'm doing this because it's faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What’s in your question is a linguistic issue, and linguistically what you are asking for is impossible and wouldn’t work even if it were possible. The code in the completion handler cannot magically reach out and nilify your reference to something.

To see why, imagine if this *were* possible! No one could write any code, our apps would always be mysteriously failing or crashing, because we could never be sure whether our reference to something had been magically destroyed by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

in objective-C, __ make your variable shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or created within the variable’s lexical scope. In this case i suggest you should create a flag and in block, you call another function to do something with the view. I think it's a bad way to keep a UI component as a shared variable. It may crash your apps sometimes.